# How to put a polygon layer under the streets layer in Google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi. I have a question about polygons in Google maps v3. How to put them under the street's layer in Google maps API v3?

This is my map: http://gidzior.net/map/ As you can see, the darker area is above the streets. Is there a way to put it under the streets?

Google maps script:

```
var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
  var markerArray = [];
  var position;
  var marker = null;
  var polyline = null;
  var poly2 = null;
  var speed = 0.0000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  var zoomed;
  var zoomedd;
  var zoomeddd;

  var step = 50; // 5; // metres

  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;
  var timerHandle = null;

  var size = new google.maps.Size(26,25);
  var start_point = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
  var foothold = new google.maps.Point(13,15);

  var car_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://fama.net.pl/echo/www/img/map/car.png", size, start_point, foothold);

  var size2 = new google.maps.Size(87,87);
  var start_point2 = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
  var foothold2 = new google.maps.Point(43,87);

  var endIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://fama.net.pl/echo/www/img/map/end.png", size2, start_point2, foothold2);

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: car_icon,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
    return marker;
}

function createEndMarker(latlng, label, html) {
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: endIcon,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
    return marker;
}

function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var pinkParksStyles = [ { featureType: "road", stylers: [ { lightness: 100 } ] },{ featureType: "landscape", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [ { hue: "#0091ff" }, { saturation: 42 }, { lightness: -44 } ] },{ featureType: "landscape", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" }, { saturation: 32 } ] },{ featureType: "transit", stylers: [ { lightness: 100 } ] },{ featureType: "road.local", stylers: [ { visibility: "simplified" } ] },{ featureType: "poi", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] },{ featureType: "road", elementType: "labels", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] },{ } ]

    var pinkMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(pinkParksStyles,
    {name: "Mapa Echo"});

    // Create a map and center it on Warszawa.
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'pink_parks']
    },
      navigationControlOptions: 
        {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
        }
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set('pink_parks', pinkMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('pink_parks');

    var myCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(52.179774,21.022171),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.182773,21.023030),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.186562,21.024403),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.194324,21.023974),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.200111,21.023416),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.205423,21.022558),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.211498,21.020069),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.217152,21.016807),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.216915,21.015691),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.216810,21.014747),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.216968,21.011657),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.217125,21.008868),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.216968,21.004748),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.216231,20.990543),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.214864,20.988998),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.213497,20.988955),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.211604,20.988740),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.202793,20.985736),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.194008,20.982732),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.198190,20.984191),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.193061,20.982432),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.192035,20.984964),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.190562,20.986423),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.187220,20.986938),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.171747,20.987367),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.166167,21.016979),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.179774,21.022171)
];
var polyOptions = new google.maps.Polygon({
path: myCoordinates,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: "#005f8c",
      fillOpacity: 0.5
});
var it = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
it.setMap(map);


    address = 'warszawa'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    });

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
  }



    var steps = []

    function calcRoute(){

if (timerHandle) { clearTimeout(timerHandle); }
if (marker) { marker.setMap(null);}
polyline.setMap(null);
poly2.setMap(null);
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
      suppressMarkers:true,
      polylineOptions:{strokeColor:'#96C11F'}
    }
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: travelMode,
            waypoints: [{
                location:new google.maps.LatLng(52.185570, 20.997255),
                stopover:false}],
            optimizeWaypoints: false
        };

        // Route the directions and pass the response to a
        // function to create markers for each step.
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation = new Object();
            endLocation = new Object();

            // For each route, display summary information.
        var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
        var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
              if (i == 0) { 
                startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                //marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
                marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
              }
              endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
              endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
              var steps = legs[i].steps;
              for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
                  polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                  bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                }
              }
            }

            polyline.setMap(map);
            document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = (polyline.Distance()/1000).toFixed(2)+" km";
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            createEndMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
            map.setZoom(18);
            startAnimation();
            zoomed=false;
            zoomedd=false;
            zoomeddd=false;
            step = 50;
            }                                                    
        });
    }

      var tick = 100; // milliseconds
      var eol;
      var k=0;
      var stepnum=0;
      var speed = "";
      var lastVertex = 1;

//=============== animation functions ======================
      function updatePoly(d) {
        // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

        if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
           if (poly2.getPath().getLength()>1) {
             poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength()-1)
           }
           poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
        } else {
          poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),endLocation.latlng);
        }
      }

      function animate(d) {
// alert("animate("+d+")");
        if (d>eol) {;
          map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
          marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
          return;
        }
        if (d>eol-20000 && zoomeddd!=true) {
          map.setZoom(12); // or whatever value
          zoomeddd=true;
        }
        if (d>eol-10000 && zoomedd!=true) {
          map.setZoom(13); // or whatever value
          zoomedd=true;
        }
        if (d>eol-1500 && zoomed!=true) {
          map.setZoom(15); // or whatever value
          step = 15;
          zoomed=true;
        }
        var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
        map.panTo(p);
        marker.setPosition(p);
        updatePoly(d);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
      }

function startAnimation() {
        eol=polyline.Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
        // map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(polyline.getAt(0),G_START_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(polyline.getVertex(polyline.getVertexCount()-1),G_END_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(marker);
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:10});
        // map.addOverlay(poly2);
        setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: 8 years ago there was no such possibility, currently I do not know but rather nothing has changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but there is no direct way to do this using the out-of-the-box API provided overlays, such as: `Circle`, `GroundOverlay`, `InfoWindow`, `Marker`, `Polygon`, or `Polyline`. There are even limitations within this group of overlays. For example, there is no way to have a `Polyline` appear above a `Marker`. If you would like to see some changes in the way this works, your only option right now is to make an enhancement request at: [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

As an aside, I think that adding content beneath the road markings would tend to make it appear that it was actually part of the Google Maps content, rather than something custom that has been added, and more than likely leading to confusion.