# Demarcate residential blocks in Google Maps without covering roads

Tags: javascript, google-maps

For a project I'm working on I need to demarcate some blocks of houses with colored overlays.

The problem is I don't have the path coordinates of these blocks so I must generate them.

I started by writing code that would construct paths from mouse click and I clicked around their perimeters. However, when I zoomed in closer I noticed my paths were wonky or close to the road at one zoom but distant at another.

So I next used the directions API to generate paths like so:

```
                var path = [],
                    poly,
                    service = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
    if (path.length == 0) {
        path.push(evt.latLng);
        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map });
        poly.setPath(path);
    } else {
        service.route({
            origin: path[path.length - 1],
            destination: evt.latLng,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                path = path.concat(result.routes[0].overview_path);
                poly.setPath(path);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This works really well creating paths that snap to the roads.

[image: Path generation]

However when I use this data to generate my polygons the polygons actually lie on top of the streets.

[image: Paths are covering the streets]

**Is there a way to prevent my overlays covering the roads**
- either by setting the zIndex of the overlay or streets
- or by employing a different path generating method.

Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated,

THANKS GUYS!

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725873/how-to-put-a-polygon-layer-under-the-streets-layer-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: @Duncan_m thanks. Yeah I think this can't be easily solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it appears this is a limitation of the Maps API. Using the directions API draws paths on the road. Can't do much about that. :(