# How to show street numbers over the colored polygon in google maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

In my web application we need show colored polygons on google maps tiles. I am adding data as **`geoJson`** to Google Map. Sample **`geoJson`** looks like below.

```
  var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "count": 1,
  "features": [
    {
      "id": 4813444,
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                174.7195396833,
                -36.8564663333
              ],
              [
                174.7196494333,
                -36.8563847667
              ],
              [
                174.7196634333,
                -36.85637435
              ],
              [
                174.7196478167,
                -36.8563614167
              ],
              [
                174.7193567667,
                -36.8561201667
              ],
              [
                174.7192242167,
                -36.8562234167
              ],
              [
                174.7195123,
                -36.8564622333
              ],
              [
                174.7195278333,
                -36.8564751167
              ],
              [
                174.7195396833,
                -36.8564663333
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "color": "#232121"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Adding **Json** to Google map as below.

```
map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
```

Used below code to set styles on colored polygons.

```
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var color = feature.getProperty('color');
    return({
      fillColor: color,
      strokeWeight: 0
    });
  });
```

**My Problem is,**

Here colored tile number is not clear because of the color.
Can Show it like below image.

**Use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sudarshanadayananda/rduvawyk/38/) to give me a solution.**

Need to tile looks like below.

[image]

Any help or tip to proceed highly appreciated.

Comment: Please mention reason those who vote to **close** this question

Comment: Your question is too broad, that's what the close votes tell you. No attempt at doing it. What you call *tile numbers* are street numbers, part of the image tiles. Also this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10725873/1238965), the answer there is still valid. You can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling few day I could find a solution.

I am posting as this will be helpful to someone who struggling on this.

My approach,

- Create new **`OverlayView`** on Map.
- Create **`StyledMapType`** for labels.
- Set above **`OverlayView`** to existing map.
- Set **`zIndex`** style for fifth **`firstChild`**.

Below is working code.

```
  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  var labelsMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
    {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#777777'}]},
    {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
    {
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off',
        color: '#17263c',
        strokeWeight: 2
      }]
    },

    {
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'on',
        color: '#17263c',
        strokeWeight: 2
      }]
    }
  ], {
    name: 'Labels'
  });    
  map.overlayMapTypes.push(labelsMapType);  
  overlay.setMap(map)
  setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('map_canvas').firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.style.zIndex = 102;
}, 2000);
```

**[Working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sudarshanadayananda/oryp729q/15/)**

**Hope this will help someone.**

Comment: Prone to total failure the day Google changes something in the HTML structure of the map as it makes use of undocumented ways to achieve something that is not supposed to be achievable at the current state of their product.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Totally agree with you. But there is no way to achieve what in the question using Google Map API. I know this is a silly answer. but it is working and thought will help someone who wants to do what in the question.

Comment: Seems not to work in Germany (tested fiddle). Yes we do have house numbers ;-)